# Отсутствует заголовок CORS «Access-Control-Allow-Origin»

Tags: google-apps-script

При попытке запроса с помощью **fetch** выдают данную ошибку. Что мне нужно добавить в свой скрипт в **Google Apps Scripts**, чтобы запросы были разрешены?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я нашел ответ спустя время используйте это

```
const user = "тут ваши данные";
const progress = "тут тоже";

var url = тут sheet апи;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", url);

xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(xhr.status);
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }};

var data = "user="+user+"&progress="+progress+""(ключ="данные"&ключ="данные");

xhr.send(data);
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что такое XMLHttpRequest(). Дело в том, что в документации Google-Apps-Script такого нет.

Answer (score 0):

Ничего добавлять не нужно. Необходимо настраивать сервер, к которому отправляются запросы.